# Not able to install RopenCVLite in window os, while working in R

Tags: r, windows, opencv, cmake

I am trying to install RopenCVLite, working in window os. 
I am working in  RStudio 3.5.0 in a Windows 7, 64-bit environment.

I am following the installation process tutorial 
https://swarm-lab.github.io/ROpenCVLite/articles/install.html

First I have installed Cmake on my computer.

Then I tried to run below code in R, to install "RopenCVLite"

```
install.packages("pkgbuild") # pkgbuild is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
install.packages("devtools") # make sure you have the latest version from CRAN
library(devtools) # load package
devtools::install_github("r-lib/pkgbuild") # install updated version of pkgbuild from GitHub
library(pkgbuild) # load package
find_rtools() # should be TRUE, assuming you have Rtools 3.5



devtools::install_github("swarm-lab/ROpenCVLite")
```

I am getting following error

```
> devtools::install_github("swarm-lab/ROpenCVLite")
Downloading GitHub repo swarm-lab/ROpenCVLite@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/swarm-lab/ROpenCVLite/zipball/master
Installing ROpenCVLite
"C:/MANUAL~1/R-35~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \
  INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmps5sa30/devtools1798506c6333/swarm-lab-ROpenCVLite-b9fcf19"  \
  --library="C:/Manually saved/R-3.5.0/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'ROpenCVLite' ...
+ set -e
+ mkdir inst/tmp
+ mkdir inst/opencv/
+ cd inst/tmp/
+ Rscript -e 'download.file("https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.1.tar.gz", "opencv-3.4.1.tar.gz")'
trying URL 'https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 87051748 bytes (83.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 83.0 MB

+ tar zxvf opencv-3.4.1.tar.gz
+ cp ../cap_dshow.cpp opencv-3.4.1/modules/videoio/src/
+ cd opencv-3.4.1
+ '[' -d C:/MANUAL~1/R-35~1.0/bin/x64 ']'
+ mkdir build64
+ cd build64
+ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++.exe -DCMAKE_RC_COMPILER=C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/windres.exe -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Rtools/bin/make.exe -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_contrib_world=OFF -DBUILD_matlab=OFF -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_photo=OFF -DBUILD_PROTOBUF=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../../../opencv/ ../
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in

CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.

ERROR: configuration failed for package 'ROpenCVLite'
* removing 'C:/Manually saved/R-3.5.0/library/ROpenCVLite'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Any suggestion is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Avjit,hope this still help you install ROpenCVLite. I encountered similar error issue just today and it shows

```
cmake: not found
```

I was able to figure out and the reason why install is failing when using command:

```
devtools::install_github("swarm-lab/ROpenCVLite")
```

it's because when you install cmake, it create its own Path folder under Program Files (on my machine). The sequence should be to install Rtools first on the root folder C such as this:

```
 C:\Rtools
```

After installation, then install CMake but need to change the Path folder to C:\Rtools, it will create and install CMake under Rtools. This installation message is how I figured out the sequence. THe script is looking at CMake under the Rtools folder:

```
+ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++.exe -DCMAKE_RC_COMPILER=C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/windres.exe -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Rtools/bin/make.exe -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_contrib_world=OFF -DBUILD_matlab=OFF -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_photo=OFF -DBUILD_PROTOBUF=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../../../opencv/ ../
```

CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!

You should be able to install ROpenCVLite without any issue. Hope this helps and if so, kindly put a check mark.